# How can i create my application's package folder to directory ../Android/Data?

Tags: android

This is what I am using:

```
File mediaStorageDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MyDir");

mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

//This will Create an internal directory;
File myAppDir = context.getDir("myAppDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//To Get a file from the directory.
File myFile= new File(myAppDir, "myFile");

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
public static final String CAMERA_DIR = "/android/data/YourPackageName/";
```

**// to Create call this**

```
CreateDirByName("database");
```

**// Method to Create**

```
  public static     String CreateDirByName(String subdir){
        String path = null;
        if(!IsSdcardAvailable()){
            return null;
        }

        try{
            File newdir =  new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + CAMERA_DIR +subdir );
            if(!newdir.exists())
            {
                newdir.mkdirs(); 
            }
            path=  newdir.getPath();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            path= null; 
        }
        return path;

    }
```

**// to check SdCard**

```
public static   Boolean IsSdcardAvailable()
    {
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;

        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false; 
        } 
        else
        {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        }
        return( mExternalStorageWriteable);
    }
```